# Assuming a key of E Major, how does I -> V6 -> bIII -> bvii -> I relate?

Tags: chord-progressions

I'm a music theory beginner and was just noodling on my keyboard, but the mentioned chord progression seems to work, and I am not certain why.  Am I doing some sort of circle of fifths modulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, just know that the fact of E major has no bearing on the answer here. The chord progression is key-independent.

The bIII and bVII chords are borrowed from the relative minor (so, for example E minor) and operate as extensions of the V6 chord.

bVII to I is a common progression in jazz and popular music, often called the "backdoor progression". For more on that, see [Why does C9 sound so good resolving to D major 7](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/108097/70803).

The bIII and bVII are, indeed, related through the circle of fifths, though they would more commonly be found in the other order. bVII is the V chord relative to bIII (e.g., in E major, D [bVII] is the dominant chord of A [bIII]).

Why it sounds good is ultimate a matter of personal aesthetics, but ultimate it is a sort of "circle of fifths thing" in terms of I - V and bIII - bVI. My interpretation is that it's close to I - V - bVI - bVII - I, with bIII substituting for bVI.

(Note: there is no modulation here in the strict sense. A modulation is a larger-scale change of key. "Tonicization" refers to a small-scale key change. But in this case neither term really applies. These are just "borrowed chords" or "modal mixture". You can search those terms on this site to learn more.)

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much, Aaron.  I'll keep browsing and exploring.  I'd upvote if I could :D

Answer (score 3):

As you get into more advanced harmonies, you'll notice a few patterns.  One of them is that pretty much any two triads that share a note can follow each other.  Depending on the shared note, you'll get either a motion by 4th or 5th, or motion by thirds.

The ♭III shares as its 3rd the root of the V chord, and moving between them gives a nice little half-step motion on the other two notes.

It's also useful if you want to move to the tonic minor, since the ♭III introduces the minor 3rd of the i chord.